Who is the wizard in the painting within J. Pippin's Potion Shop in Hogsmeade?
When you enter the J. Pippin's Shop for the first time in Hogsmeade, then Parry Pippin mentions that his grandfather made him say the full name of the shop every time.
And when you look at the wall above him, then there's a photo of an older wizard:


Who is the wizard in this photo?
Could it maybe be his grandfather or father?
